# doctrine beetwen expr doesn't work for me

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('u')
   ->from('AppBundle:User','u')
   ->join('AppBundle:Profile', 'p')
   ->add(
       'where', 
       $qb->expr()
          ->between(
              'p.rank',
              ':min',
              ':max'
          )
   )
   ->andWhere('u.id != :id')
   ->setParameters(array('min' => $minimumRank, 'max' => $maximumRank, 'id' => $user->getId()));

   $query = $qb->getQuery();
   $players = $query->getResult();
```

The problem with my query is that my result always returns every record from the database. I tried to come up with a different solution but to no avail. I am looking for some suggestions. If you need more information please let me know.

User.php

 `/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     message = "Nie podałeś nazwy użytkownika"
     * )
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 3,
     *      minMessage = "Twoja nazwa użytkownika powinna składać się z minimum {{ limit }} znaków",
     * )
     */
    protected $username;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     message = "Nie podałeś hasła"
     * )
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 6,
     *      minMessage = "Twoje hasło powinno składać się z minimum {{ limit }} znaków",
     * )
     */
    protected $password;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     message = "Nie podałeś adresu e-mail"
     * )
     * @Assert\Email(
     *      message = "Wprowadzony adres-email jest nieprawidłowy"
     * )
     */
    protected $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $enabled;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $confirmationToken;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $time;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $lastLogin;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $locked;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $expired;
    protected $expiresAt;
    protected $credentialsExpired;
    protected $credentialsExpireAt;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $firstLogin;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $passwordRequestedAt;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", orphanRemoval=true, inversedBy="user")
     */
    protected $profile;`

Profile.php
`/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="steamID", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $steamID;
    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
    private $name;
    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
    private $surname;
    /**
        * @var string
        *
        * @ORM\Column(name="rank", type="integer", nullable=true)
        */
    private $rank;
    /**
    *@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="profile")
    */
    private $user;`

Comment: Have you taken a look at how the query is compiled to SQL (`$qb->getQuery()->getSql()`) or DQL (`$qb->getDql()`)? Firs thing i would do is make sure those are what you expect. If they look correct, then check that values you are passing as the params.

Comment: `string 'SELECT a0_.id AS id0, a0_.username AS username1, a0_.password AS password2, a0_.email AS email3, a0_.enabled AS enabled4, a0_.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token5, a0_.time AS time6, a0_.last_login AS last_login7, a0_.locked AS locked8, a0_.expired AS expired9, a0_.first_login AS first_login10, a0_.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at11, a0_.profile_id AS profile_id12 FROM app_users a0_ INNER JOIN app_profiles a1_ ON ((a1_.rank BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND a0_.id <> ?)' (length=480)`

Comment: values are not passed in

Comment: actually IIRC those methods do not print the values in the query, only the placeholders (and always as `?` wether you used named or positional). It looks like the problem is the join itself.. it has your `WHERE` conditions in the `ON` clause and no `a0_.id = a1_.user_id` (or whatever your join column is).

Comment: what can I do with that then?

Answer (score 0):

Try by this way:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u')
    ->from('AppBundle:User','u')
    ->leftJoin('u.profile', 'p')
    ->where('u.id != :id')
    ->andWhere('p.rank > :min') 
    ->andWhere('p.rank < :max') 
    ->setParameters([
        'min' => $minimumRank, 
        'max' => $maximumRank, 
        'id'  => $user->getId()
    ])
   ->getQuery();

$players = $qb->getResult();
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Did you try with a leftjoin? I edit my post in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is the join itself.. it has your `WHERE` conditions in the `ON` clause and no `a0_.id = a1_.user_id` (or whatever your join column is).

I could have swore that the QB form the EntityManager did some magic an figured out the join condition for you, but it would seem that is not the case, and since you did not specify it rolls your where conditions in. Try the following:

```
$qb->select('u')
    ->from('AppBundle:User', u)
    // changed to use the entity's property on User
    ->join('u.profile', 'p')
    ->where($qb->expr()->between(
        'p.rank',
        ':min',
        ':max'
    ))
    ->andWhere('u.id != :id')
    ->setParameters(array('min' => $minimumRank, 'max' => $maximumRank, 'id' => $user->getId()));
```

Comment: `->join('AppBundle:Profile', 'p', 'ON', 'u.id = p.user_id')`
Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON'

Comment: Hmmm thats odd... try the constant `\Doctrine\ORM\QueryExpr\Join::ON` if thats gives you the same issue try using `'WITH'`.

Comment: namespace `\Doctrine\ORM\QueryExpr\Join::ON` don't exists

Comment: There was a missing slash from my C&P... `\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::ON`. But i dont think thats going to work... try the `'WITH'` first. I think maybe the on is misleading and its not for what one would think.

Comment: should it look like `->join('AppBundle:Profile', 'p WITH u.id = p.id')` ?

Comment: no like this: `->join('AppBundle:Profile', 'p', 'WITH', 'u.id = p.WHATEVER_COLUMN_IS_THE_FK_TO_USER')`

Comment: i dont have foreign key in profile table, only profile_id in users

Comment: Ok, in that case it would be `'u.profile_id = p.id'` as your last argument. That of course assumes the `users.profile_id` is in fact the same value as `profile.id`... but i dont see how it would not be, unless im missing something very important (and irregular) about your db schema.

Comment: `Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\User has no field or association named profile_id` got this

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your schema for the User and Profile entities.

Comment: added entities schema

Comment: See the change in my answer.. I think the problem is that im thinking of the DBAL query build which uses columns, the one from ORM uses entity properties. So you should be doing `->join('u.profile', 'p')` i think.